Images can not be loaded next.js 14 in production build
I have a small, simple application where I am adding PDFs through an admin web portal and assigning them to suppliers I have in the database. However, in production mode, when I run this production build, pictures load normally. But after uploading a new picture with a new name and trying to show it, it does not load, even if the link is correct after loading it from the database and it is located in the public folder. I then need to restart the server, and again the PDFs show correctly. Why is this happening? Why do I need to restart the server for everything to work? I need this to be dynamic.
here is my code for loading information from database:
/app/api/suppliers/route.ts
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { getSuppliers, addSupplier, updateSupplier, deleteSupplier } from '@/lib/suppliers';

export async function GET() {
  try {
    const suppliers = await getSuppliers();
    const response = NextResponse.json(suppliers, { status: 200 });
  
    return response;
  } catch  {
    return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Error fetching suppliers' }, { status: 500 });
  }
}

here is function from /app/lib/suppliers.ts
import sql from "mssql";
import { connectToDb } from "./db";

export async function getSuppliers() {
  const pool = await connectToDb();
  try {
    const result = await pool.request()
      .query(`SELECT s.id, s.Name as [name], s.tel, s.price, si.imagePath 
FROM suppliers s
left join supplier_images si on si.id = s.image_id`);
    return result.recordset;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching suppliers:", error);
    throw error;
  }
}


this is code where I am uploading files:
/app/admin/upload-menu/page.tsx
'use client';
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'; // Zabezpečenie dynamického spracovania

import React from 'react';
import UploadMenuImages from '@/components/Admin/UploadMenuImages';

const UploadMenu: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div className="p-2">
      <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold mb-4 text-yellow-600">Správa menu</h1>
      <UploadMenuImages />
    </div>
  );
};

export default UploadMenu;



and here function of component it self used in code:
/components/Admin/UploadMenuImages.tsx
export const dynamic = "force-dynamic"; // Zabezpečenie dynamického spracovania
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

interface Supplier {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  attachment: string | null; // Názov aktuálneho súboru/prílohy
  fileExists: boolean; // Stav na označenie existencie súboru
}

const UploadMenuImages: React.FC = () => {
  const [selectedSupplier, setSelectedSupplier] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [selectedAttachment, setSelectedAttachment] = useState<string | null>(
    null
  ); // Na uchovanie názvu prílohy pre náhľad
  const [image, setImage] = useState<File | null>(null);
  const [suppliers, setSuppliers] = useState<Supplier[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchSuppliers();
  }, []);

  // Upravená funkcia na načítanie dodávateľov a prispôsobenie dát štruktúre `Supplier`
  const fetchSuppliers = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`/api/suppliers`);
      const data = response.data as {
        id: number;
        name: string;
        imagePath: string | null;
      }[];

      // Mapovanie API dát na štruktúru `Supplier` a kontrola existencie súborov
      const formattedSuppliers: Supplier[] = await Promise.all(
        data.map(async (supplier) => {
          const fileExists = supplier.imagePath
            ? await checkFileExists(supplier.imagePath)
            : false;
          return {
            id: supplier.id,
            name: supplier.name,
            attachment: supplier.imagePath || null, // Priradenie attachmentu, ak existuje
            fileExists, // Kontrola, či súbor existuje
          };
        })
      );

      setSuppliers(formattedSuppliers);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching suppliers:", error);
    }
  };

  // Funkcia na overenie existencie súboru
  const checkFileExists = async (filePath: string) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`/api/file-exists?filePath=${filePath}`);
      return response.data.exists;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error checking file existence:", error);
      return false;
    }
  };

  const handleFileChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (event.target.files) {
      setImage(event.target.files[0]);
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    if (!selectedSupplier || !image) {
      alert("Vyberte dodávateľa a súbor");
      return;
    }

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("supplierId", selectedSupplier);
    formData.append("file", image);

    try {
      const response = await axios.post(`/api/menu/upload`, formData);
      if (response.status === 200) {
        alert(`Súbor bol úspešne nahraný: ${response.data.filePath}`);
        fetchSuppliers(); // Obnovíme zoznam dodávateľov
      } else {
        alert("Chyba pri nahrávaní súboru");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Chyba pri odosielaní súboru:", error);
    }
  };

  const handleRowClick = (supplier: Supplier) => {
    //console.log("Selected supplier:", supplier);
    if (supplier.attachment && supplier.fileExists) {
      setSelectedAttachment(supplier.attachment); // Nastavíme náhľad
    } else {
      setSelectedAttachment(null); // Ak príloha neexistuje, nastavíme na null
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <select
        onChange={(e) => setSelectedSupplier(e.target.value)}
        className="mb-4"
      >
        <option value="">Vyber dodávateľa</option>
        {suppliers.map((supplier) => (
          <option key={supplier.id} value={supplier.id.toString()}>
            {supplier.name}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>

      <input type="file" onChange={handleFileChange} className="mb-4" />
      <button
        onClick={handleSubmit}
        className="bg-blue-500 text-white px-4 py-2"
      >
        Nahrať
      </button>

      {/* Tabuľka dodávateľov s označením existencie príloh */}
      <table className="min-w-full bg-white mt-4">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th className="border px-4 py-2">Dodávateľ</th>
            <th className="border px-4 py-2">Príloha</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {suppliers.map((supplier) => (
            <tr
              key={supplier.id}
              className={`cursor-pointer ${
                supplier.fileExists ? "bg-green-100" : "bg-red-100"
              }`}
              onClick={() => handleRowClick(supplier)} // Kliknutie na riadok
            >
              <td className="border px-4 py-2">{supplier.name}</td>
              <td className="border px-4 py-2">
                {supplier.attachment ? supplier.attachment : "Žiadna príloha"}
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>

      {/* Zobrazenie náhľadu prílohy, ak bola vybratá */}
      {selectedAttachment && (
        <div className="mt-4">
          <h3>Náhľad prílohy:</h3>
          {/* Ak je príloha obrázok, zobrazíme ju */}
          {selectedAttachment.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/i) ? (
            <img
              src={`${selectedAttachment}`}
              alt="Náhľad obrázka"
              className="w-full h-auto"
            />
          ) : selectedAttachment.endsWith(".pdf") ? (
            // Ak je príloha PDF, zobrazíme PDF viewer
            <object
              data={`${selectedAttachment}`}
              type="application/pdf"
              width="100%"
              height="600px"
            >
              <p>PDF nie je možné zobraziť.</p>
            </object>
          ) : (
            <p>Formát súboru nie je podporovaný pre náhľad.</p>
          )}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default UploadMenuImages;

and also api for uploading it:
/app/api/menu/upload/route.ts
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import multer from "multer";
import path from "path";
import { saveSupplierImage } from "@/lib/suppliers";
import fs from "fs";


// Nastavenie `multer` na ukladanie súborov do priečinka public/uploads
multer({
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination: "./public/uploads", // Umiestnenie nahraných súborov
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + "-" + Math.round(Math.random() * 1e9);
      cb(
        null,
        file.fieldname + "-" + uniqueSuffix + path.extname(file.originalname)
      ); // Generovanie názvu súboru s príponou
    },
  }),
  limits: { fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 10 }, // Obmedzenie veľkosti súboru na 10 MB
});

// API route na spracovanie nahrania súboru spolu s údajmi o dodávateľovi
export const POST = async (req: Request) => {
  const formData = await req.formData();

  const file = formData.get("file") as File;
  const supplierId = formData.get("supplierId");

  if (!file || !supplierId) {
    console.error("Súbor alebo ID dodávateľa nebolo poskytnuté.");
    return NextResponse.json({ message: "Chýba súbor alebo dodávateľ" }, { status: 400 });
  }

  const filePath = `/uploads/${file.name}`;
  
  // Uložme súbor na disk
  const buffer = await file.arrayBuffer();
 
  fs.writeFileSync(`./public${filePath}`, Buffer.from(buffer));

  // Uloženie cesty k súboru do databázy
  await saveSupplierImage(supplierId.toString(), filePath);

  return NextResponse.json({
    message: "Súbor bol úspešne nahratý",
    filePath,
  });
};


// Zakázanie natívneho spracovania tela v Next.js 14
export const runtime = 'nodejs';
export const preferredRegion = 'auto';
//export const disableBodyParser = true;


Thx for you help guys.
My code is using Axios instead of Fetch. I tried it first with Fetch and used all cache controls I found, but none of them helped. Then I switched to using Axios, and it was the same result.
I need this to be dynamically updated without a server restart.
Please help.

The /public folder is meant to store static files (JavaScript, CSS, images etc), so using it to serve dynamically uploaded files isn't a great solution.
You'd need to store the files on an external service, e.g. AWS S3. Then you can store the URL to access it in your DB, and fetch the file from S3 with that URL whenever a user requests it.

yes I undestand that, but this images you mentioning is same problem, when I want to add image to this public folder throw UI its same problem, if its public it should work as AWS. Where is difference between AWS and public folder? Also why I need to use AWS if I have my own server where I would like to store data, its not making sense. Thx
